# Reading Windows event log using JNA provides me only part of the description available in Event Veiwer

Tags: jna

> This is my code Provide me details where am going wrong so that am
>   getting only the part of the description available

========================================================================
http://code.dblock.org/jna-reading-windows-event-log-entries-in-java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void testReadEventLogEntries() throws CharacterCodingException {
    final Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    final CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
    final CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
    int i = 0;// loop contro variable
    String type = null; // Type of the event
    String user = null;
    String str[] = { "System", "Application" };
    while (i < 2) {
        System.out.println("\n\n" + str[i]);
        HANDLE h = Advapi32.INSTANCE.OpenEventLog(null, str[i]); 
        IntByReference pnBytesRead = new IntByReference();
        IntByReference pnMinNumberOfBytesNeeded = new IntByReference();
        Memory buffer = new Memory(1024 * 64);
        IntByReference pOldestRecord = new IntByReference();
        int dwRecord = pOldestRecord.getValue();
        int rc = 0;
        while (true) { // Travesing the read log records
            if (!Advapi32.INSTANCE.ReadEventLog(h,
                    WinNT.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
                            | WinNT.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ, 0, buffer,
                    (int) buffer.size(), pnBytesRead,
                    pnMinNumberOfBytesNeeded)) {
                rc = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError();
                if (rc == W32Errors.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
                    buffer = new Memory(pnMinNumberOfBytesNeeded.getValue());
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
            int dwRead = pnBytesRead.getValue();
            Pointer pevlr = buffer;
            while (dwRead > 0) {
                EVENTLOGRECORD record = new EVENTLOGRECORD(pevlr);
                EventLogRecord event = new EventLogRecord(pevlr);
                org.hyperic.sigar.win32.EventLogRecord sigar;
                EventLog log = new EventLog();
                if (record.EventType.intValue() == 1)
                    type = "Error";
                else if (record.EventType.intValue() == 10)
                    type = "Failure Audit";
                else if (record.EventType.intValue() == 8)
                    type = "Sucess Audit";
                else if (record.EventType.intValue() == 4)
                    type = "Information";
                else
                    type = "Warning";
                ByteBuffer names = pevlr
                        .getByteBuffer(
                                record.size(),
                                (record.UserSidLength.intValue() != 0 ? record.UserSidOffset
                                        .intValue() : record.StringOffset
                                        .intValue())
                                        - record.size());
                names.position(0);
                CharBuffer namesBuf = names.asCharBuffer();
                String[] splits = namesBuf.toString().split("\0");
                if (record.UserSidLength.intValue() != 0) {
                    ByteBuffer usersid = pevlr.getByteBuffer(
                            record.UserSidOffset.intValue(),
                            record.UserSidLength.intValue());
                    usersid.position(0);
                    CharBuffer sidBuf = usersid.asCharBuffer();
                    String[] sp = sidBuf.toString().split("\0");
                    // System.out.println(sp[0] + sp[1] + sp[2]);
                    /*
                     * dst.get user= new String(dst);
                     */
                } else {
                    user = "N/A";
                }

                System.out.println(type + "\t" + toDate(record) + "\t"
                        + event.getSource() + "\t" + record.EventCategory
                        + "\t" + record.EventID.shortValue() + "\t" + user
                        + "\t" + splits[1]);

                ByteBuffer strings = pevlr.getByteBuffer(
                        record.StringOffset.longValue(),
                        record.DataOffset.intValue()
                                - record.StringOffset.intValue());
                CharBuffer stringsBuf = strings.asCharBuffer();

                System.out.println("Desc: " + stringsBuf.toString());

                dwRecord++;
                dwRead -= record.Length.intValue();
                pevlr = pevlr.share(record.Length.intValue());

            }

        }

        i++;
    }

}

// Method to convert the timestamp to formated date
public Date toDate(EVENTLOGRECORD record) {
    Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(record.TimeWritten.longValue() * 1000);
    Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
    return date;

}
```

}

Comment: using Byte buffer i get a part of the description data available in event viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Finally I figured out the solution....The description returned by the
>   above code is just the insertion strings needed to build the message.
>   Instead of using jna I used WMI  which is simple to use and more handy

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws COMException {
    String computerName = ".";
    String userName = "";
    String password = "";
    String namespace = "root/cimv2";
    String Message = "";
    String queryProcessor = "Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent where Logfile='System'or Logfile='Application'";
    DispatchPtr dispatcher = null;

    try {

        ISWbemLocator locator = new ISWbemLocator(
                "WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
        ISWbemServices wbemServices = locator.ConnectServer(computerName,
                namespace, userName, password, "", "", 0, dispatcher);

        ISWbemObjectSet wbemObjectSet = wbemServices.ExecQuery(
                queryProcessor, "WQL", 0, null);

        DispatchPtr[] results = new DispatchPtr[wbemObjectSet.getCount()];
        IUnknown unknown = wbemObjectSet.get_NewEnum();
        IEnumVariant enumVariant = (IEnumVariant) unknown
                .queryInterface(IEnumVariant.class);

        enumVariant.Next(wbemObjectSet.getCount(), results);

        for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            ISWbemObject wbemObject = (ISWbemObject) results[i]
                    .queryInterface(ISWbemObject.class);
            if (wbemObject.get("Message") != null) {
                Message = (String) wbemObject.get("Message");
            } else {
                Message = "The description for Event ID ("
                        + wbemObject.get("EventCode")
                        + " ) in Source ( "
                        + wbemObject.get("SourceName")
                        + ") cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details.";
            }
            System.out.println(wbemObject.get("Logfile") + "\t"
                    + wbemObject.get("Type") + "\t"
                    + toDate(wbemObject.get("TimeGenerated").toString())
                    + "\t"
                    + toTime(wbemObject.get("TimeGenerated").toString())
                    + "\t" + wbemObject.get("EventCode") + "\t"
                    + wbemObject.get("ComputerName") + "\t" + Message);
            // System.out.println(wbemObject.GetObjectText_(0));

        }

    } catch (COMException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String toDate(String time) throws COMException {

    String date = time.substring(6, 8) + "-" + time.substring(4, 6) + "-"
            + time.substring(0, 4);
    return date;

}

public static String toTime(String time) throws COMException {

    String Generatedtime = time.substring(8, 10) + ":"
            + time.substring(10, 12) + ":" + time.substring(12, 14) + ":"
            + time.substring(16, 21) + "-" + "GMT" + time.substring(21, 25);
    return Generatedtime;
}
```